# Inheriting memberships through Households

Tags: civimember, households

I have some individual contacts that are related both directly, and through Households.

When one of these contacts has a membership, I want all the household members to also get that membership.

However, it seems that only the household inherits that membership, other individual contacts don't get it.

Should this work out of the box, or do I need to do something specific?

Answer (score 1):

For all individual contacts of a household to inherit a membership from another member of the household, you need to add the relationship type between the individual contacts to the membership type (e.g. Spouse of, Household Member Is, etc.) but you will not be able to modify the membership type accordingly if there are membership records associated with it:

[image]

If you want to avoid having to create a new membership type and then updating all of your existing primary membership records with that membership type, you will need a programmer who can update the membership type directly in the database and then run a query to create the related memberships.

Good luck,
Tamar

Comment: My membership types already have "Household member" as their relationship type. However, the actual memberships do not extend to all individuals in that household; only the individual that actually signed up, and the related household.

Comment: If you click on the help bubble that is contained in the red circled area of the screenshot above, you'll see an example that says for members of a household to inherit a membership, the primary member must be the household and the relationship type to include would be "Household member is". You indicate that the individual is the one signing up for the membership that is inherited by the household, so the relationship type you have is "Household member of", but you also need to add whatever relationship type exists between the individual members of the household -Spouse of, Parent of, etc.

Comment: Ok, I think I found my mistake... I had the reverse relationship (Household member) set up in my membership type...